# Error with getting the Proper id for XML parser

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, android-fragments

I am having an issue with my code. It doesn't even run the line where I set parser equal to something, when I input my fragment id as a parameter.

My XML Layout Parser Class:

```
public class XMLLayoutParser {
Context activity;
/*
 * Each constant represents an Android View type
 * Add in additional constants as needed; those here
 * are just some that seem would be most commonly needed
 */
public static final String EDIT_TEXT = "EditText";
public static final String TEXT_VIEW = "TextView";
public static final String CHECKBOX = "CheckBox";


public XMLLayoutParser(Context act){
    activity = act;
}



public HashMap<String, Integer> getElementIds(int layoutId, String viewType) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{
    //This causes the bug it is calling for xmlresourceparser to be set to the xml of the layout
    //from layout id
    //Throws an error (uncaught handler exception)
    //                         Gets Context -> get Resources -> you get the layout of the layout id in parameter (FormCreationFragment)
    XmlResourceParser parser = activity.getResources().getLayout(layoutId);

    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


    while(parser.getEventType()!=XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT){
        parser.next();
        if(parser.getEventType()==XmlResourceParser.START_TAG){
            if(parser.getName().equals(viewType)){
                if(parser.getAttributeName(0).equals("id")){
                    long viewId = parser.getIdAttributeResourceValue(0);
                    //Gets the value of tag
                    String elementType = parser.getAttributeValue(null,"tag");
                    //Puts in the tag as the key, and the id as the value
                    map.put(elementType, (int)viewId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    parser.close();

    return map;
}
```

}

The Wrapper class is suppose to call on my XML parser class to read through an XML and then alter a fragment that is calling it to either make the items visible or invisible. I made it into a Hashmap, so that I can link two Views together, the textView and the editTextView, so I can modify both items to be visible through the wrapper class.

My Wrapper Class:

```
public class Wrapper {
//FIELDS
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";


/**
 * Elements holds the elements of the form that wishes to be turned visible.
 */
private String[] Elements;

/**
 * The Fragment that will be passed in through the parameter that will change from the
 * Elements string.
 */
private android.support.v4.app.Fragment FormConstructionFragment;

/**
 * The XMLLayoutParser that parses through the layout and returns the ID, of the items located
 * within the XML file of the specific Fragment/Activity passed into it's parameter.
 */
XMLLayoutParser parser;

//CONSTRUCTOR
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Constructor for Wrapper class, reads in an array that tells this class what elements
 * to make either visible or invisible.
 *
 * @param Elements  The list of form items to either be turned invisible/visible
 */
public Wrapper(String[] Elements, android.support.v4.app.Fragment FormConstructionFragment){
    this.Elements = Elements;
    this.FormConstructionFragment = FormConstructionFragment;
    //This getActivity can be null, if it is called before the on attach of the fragment
    parser = new XMLLayoutParser(FormConstructionFragment.getActivity());


    //Changes all the elements in the String[] Elements to Visible
}
//METHODS
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Only makes one pair of items visible.
 * @param item
 */
public void makeVisible(String item){
    Log.v(TAG, "index=");
    HashMap<String, Integer> textViewMap = null;
    try {
        textViewMap = parser.getElementIds(FormConstructionFragment.getId(), XMLLayoutParser.TEXT_VIEW);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(textViewMap != null){
        //Finds the id, by giving in the key to textViewMap, then it sets text equal to the
        //textView attained

        //THE VALUE IS ALWAYS NULL!!!
        if (textViewMap.get(item) != null){
            TextView text = (TextView) FormConstructionFragment.getView().findViewById(textViewMap.get(item));

            //Gets the tag of the TextView and puts it in as a String
            String pathViewStrId = (String) text.getTag();

            //Gets the id of the Edit Text
            int patViewId = FormConstructionFragment.getResources().getIdentifier(pathViewStrId, "id", FormConstructionFragment.getView().getContext().getPackageName());

            //Finds the editText object
            EditText editView = (EditText) FormConstructionFragment.getView().findViewById(patViewId);

            //Sets the textView to be visible
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //Sets the editText to be visible
            editView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Calls the makeVisible method on every string in the array.
 */
public void makeVisibleAll(){
    for(int i = 0; i < Elements.length; i++){
        makeVisible(Elements[i]);
    }
}
```

}

To link the elements together I figured that I could use tags to get the id of one to the other. Here is my fragment's xml. So, what would happen is that with the xmlParser it would create a hashmap, and within that Hashmap it will hold the value for the textView if I put in the proper key. So with the value of textView, I can use it to get the tag to then get reference to the proper editText that is suppose to be linked to it. So when I have references to both items I can now set both of them to be visible.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:tag="emailEditText"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/passwordTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:labelFor="@+id/passwordTextView"
        android:tag="passwordEditText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

This is what shows on the stack.

05-07 18:16:08.069  16701-16701/com.scrumpy.nelson.androidform D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-07 18:16:08.069  16701-16701/com.scrumpy.nelson.androidform E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.scrumpy.nelson.androidform, PID: 16701
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090040 type #0x12 is not valid
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3932)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:2161)
            at com.scrumpy.nelson.androidform.XMLLayoutParser.getElementIds(XMLLayoutParser.java:47)
            at com.scrumpy.nelson.androidform.Wrapper.makeVisible(Wrapper.java:70)
            at com.scrumpy.nelson.androidform.FormConstructionFragment.onCreateView(FormConstructionFragment.java:46)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Comment: Which error is thrown? Please provide a stacktrace.

Comment: I put it in, sorry if I am not the most adept at this.

Comment: Looks like "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090040 type #0x12 is not valid" is the main problem. What's the value of `layoutId` when this exception is thrown? 0x7f090040 (HEX) or 2131296320 (dec)? I don't know much about Android though, but looks like there's no element with that ID in your XML file - maybe the ID is wrong?

Comment: Using the debugger, I get this id: 2131296320, so the decimal version of what you said.

Comment: Yeah, the id is wrong, I don't know why it retrieves that id however. I had the form construction fragment call .getId() in my wrapper class, so I thought that whatever fragment I put into the parameter will get it's own id and put it through the parser.